# Error in destructor in feature detector + SURF features

Tags: c++, opencv, surf

I am trying to measure the amount of local distortion in terms of the average Euclidean distance between matching keypoints in patches in successive frames of a video. The following function is called (used this [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html)) :

```
double Processing::calculate_distortion(Mat standard, Mat frame)
{
    std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;

    cout << standard.rows << ", " << frame.rows << endl;
    cout << standard.cols << ", " << frame.cols << endl;

    FastFeatureDetector detector(10);
    detector.detect( standard, keypoints_1 );
    detector.detect( frame, keypoints_2 );

    cout << keypoints_1.size() << ", " << keypoints_2.size() << endl;

    //-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
    SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;

    Mat descriptors_1, descriptors_2;

    extractor.compute( standard, keypoints_1, descriptors_1 );
    extractor.compute( frame, keypoints_2, descriptors_2 );

    cout << descriptors_1.rows << ", " << descriptors_2.rows << endl;

    cout << "BP1" << endl;

    //-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN matcher
    FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
    std::vector< DMatch > matches;
    matcher.match( descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches );

    double min_dist = 100;
    //-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
    for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_1.rows; i++ )
    {
        double dist = matches[i].distance;
        if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
    }

    cout << "BP2" << endl;

    //-- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 2*min_dist,
    //-- or a small arbitary value ( 0.02 ) in the event that min_dist is very
    //-- small)
    //-- PS.- radiusMatch can also be used here.
    double distance = 0.0;
    int count = 0;
    double limit = 2 * min_dist;
    limit = (limit > 0.02) ? limit : 0.02;

    cout << limit << endl;

    for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_1.rows; i++ )
    {
        if( matches[i].distance <= limit )
        {
            Point2f point1 = keypoints_1[matches[i].queryIdx].pt;
            Point2f point2 = keypoints_2[matches[i].trainIdx].pt;

            distance += sqrt(pow(point1.x - point2.x, 2.0) +
                             pow(point1.y - point2.y, 2.0));

            count += 1;
        }
    }

    cout << "Count : " << count << endl;

    return distance / count;
}
```

The function fails as it returns. The debugger producs the following error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x770086ce in .exe: 0xC0000005: >Access violation reading location 0xff244e8b.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this error is just too general. It appears when the object is released/deleted before something else tries to access it -> maybe dangling pointer. Since the compiler does not find it so I would guess it is either member variables or global variables. Hope this could enlighten you a little bit

Comment: @YiruiJiang I dug in a little further and found that it is most probably a problem with the FLANN matcher. The error comes from a destructor of the DescriptorCollection class in the matcher. I think perhaps the descriptors_1 and descriptors_2 are getting deleted before the matcher. Is there a way to prevent that? I tried changing the matcher to a Ptr<FlannBasedMatcher> and deleting it before the return but the application is still crashing.

Comment: Hi, since I have no access to your code, the best I can do is giving you some my ideas when I encounter/debug this problem. Go line by line when debugging, see when the exception is thrown and see which variable is already empty. Make sure you apply  "try" and "catch" to get more information. I believe you will find the problem. Good luck